# shell script cd fails even though the path is correct

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, cd

I need to do a script to extract a tar at a specified location.

I did something simple like:

```
cp test.tar /var/www/html
cd /var/www/html
tar xvf test.tar
```

If I execute the commands by hand everything is OK. If I save them in a .sh then use #bash script.sh, I get the following error ": Not a directory cd: /var/www/html". Any ideea why?

Ty for your time.

Notes: I tried the script version on a virtual machine (CentOS 5.5) and the script worked fine, the problem occurs on the real machine where I want to use it (I used same OS disk image, same configurations as on the virtual machine... this makes it really really odd for me).

Added: Also I try invoking something like service mysqld start... this also fails saying that a dir doesn't exist (still if I run by hand it works.).

Comment: if 'html' doesn't exist the copy command is going to rename your test.tar to 'html'. Make sure it's actually a directory and not a copy of your file.

Comment: Any chance you're running the script as a different user? Try adding a 'whoami' and 'ls -la /var/www' at the top of your script and compare the output they give you to what you get when you run them directly from the command line.

Comment: I solved the problem (Can any1 add this as an answer? - it is quite interesting). I created the script on a virtual machine running on windows with a centos os, the enter in windows is "\r\n" while in linux is "\n". The script worked on the vm because the code for enter was correct, while on the second computer, with native linux it was incorrect. I created exactly the same script on linux and everything went back 2 normal ;). Note... the mkdir part worked because I used another, simplified script written on linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem - it is quite interesting).

I created the script on a virtual machine running on windows with a centos os, the enter in windows is "\r\n" while in linux is "\n".

The script worked on the vm because the code for enter was correct, while on the second computer, with native linux it was incorrect. I created exactly the same script on linux and everything went back 2 normal ;).

Note... the mkdir part worked because I used another, simplified script written on linux.

Answer (score 2):

On a related note, I have found that the "~" character does not seem to work in bash, so if you are using that, try replacing it with the full path.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was running into. And a possible solution is to merely replace the ~ with $HOME on the spot (in case you cannot change the data source): 

cd ${DirectoryString/#\~/$HOME}

Comment: In what distribution and version does the '~' seem not to work in bash? Maybe `$HOME` adds up to readability, but '~' do actually work in all bash versions and distributions I know. (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `cp` might be coping test.jar to the *file* html under the www directory. Make sure that html exists and is a directory before you try to cp.

```
mkdir -p /var/www/html
cp test.tar /var/www/html
cd /var/www/html
tar xvf test.tar
```

Comment: The only way for cd to give that error message is for the target to NOT be a directory

Comment: It seems that the script created a file called html? (even thought html existed) and tried to copy in it... this solves half of problem (updated with the second half)